# Configure VSCode include path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VSCode to edit Xilinx SDK files. The VSCode issues "problems" that include path can't be found.

I used the bulb "show fixes":

> Add to "includePath": D:/Other/Xilinx/SDK/2017.4/gnu/aarch32/nt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.2.1/include

But VSCode is still complaining about the missing include path, although each `Add to "includePath"` adds a correct path to "c_cpp_properties.json" in the projects .vscode folder.

What's wrong with the include configuration?

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/standalone_bsp_0/ps7_cortexa9_0/include",
                "D:/Other/Xilinx/SDK/2017.4/gnu/aarch32/nt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.2.1/include",
                "D:/Other/Xilinx/SDK/2017.4/gnu/aarch32/nt/gcc-arm-none-eabi/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/6.2.1/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "8.1",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

That's the line complained by VSCode:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

**Edit:**

Each accepting of the "fix" causes an additional line with the same path in "includePath", but this doesn't solve the problem. So what you see in the `c_cpp_properties.json` dump is caused by the "fix".

Comment: I just noticed that you are (a) duplicating the path in the `"includePath"` property; and (b) the path shown in the message is different from the one in the configuration (i.e., in the configuration, you have `D:/Other/Xilinx/` whereas in the message it shows `D:/Xilinx/`.

Comment: @TeeKea The different path was a typo. But the duplication was a result of the automatic 'fix'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `c_cpp_properties.json` appears to have the same problems as in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57735192/2659307) I recently posted.  To summarize:

1. Add `compilerPath`.
2. Change `intelliSenseMode` to `gcc-x86` or `gcc-x64`.  (Not sure which, there is no `gcc-arm` option.)
3. Check out the [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).
4. Try running "C/C++: Log Diagnostics" and "gcc -v -E -dD".

See the linked answer for a few more hints and details.