# How to fix namespace "std" has no member "sqrt" in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am able to compile and execute my code successfully. However, VSCode keeps showing me the error message:

> namespace std has no member "sqrt".

I adjusted the properties.json. Please advice why is the vscode showing this error. I tried googling but no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>

int main() {
 double a,b,c;
 int root1, root2;


  std::cout<<"Enter a: \n";
  std::cin >> a;
  std::cout<<"Enter b: \n";
  std::cin >> b;
  std::cout<<"Enter c: \n";
  std::cin >> c;

  root1 = (-b + std::sqrt (b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
  std::cout<<"Root 1 Number: " << root1 << "\n";

  root2 = (-b - std::sqrt (b*b - 4*a*c)) / (2*a);
  std::cout<<"Root 2 Number: " << root2 << "\n";

}

json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++/backward",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++/tr1",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++/tr2"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__GNUC__=6",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++/backward",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include/c++/tr1",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/include"
                ]
            }

        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: Is it really your *editor* that gives you the errors, or is it the *compiler* and the output from it that the editor show you? There is a difference. Also, when asking questions about build errors of any kind, please copy-paste (as text) the *full* and *complete* output, even parts that might not seem relevant.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I pasted the entire code. The vscode editor keep showing this error under the problem tab. But i am able to compile and execute my code. Thats why I am thinking is this a vscode issue? or i didnt configure smth?

Comment: Configuring cpptools extension correctly, so that Intellisense works is not very straightforward.

You should check this page which describes several methods for configuring Intellisense:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Getting%20started%20with%20IntelliSense%20configuration.md

Comment: (Hope you don't mind this comment re [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58360336/3404097) you just deleted.) The boldface is the assignment.--OK. (Please read edit help & use block quotation.) But what is the diagram? Presumably attributes within a box form a set & a box-arrow-box is a FD {}->{} & other blue lines are irrelevant to that FD. However, it's not a good solution. So probably it's not the given solution.  If you made it, explain why. But that seems unlikely since you write FDs incorrectly. Where is it from? It would be helpful if you clearly explain what is going on. Good luck.

Comment: @philipxy the image is what i came out with myself. i deleted the post because i dont think you understand where i am coming from.  the image is a functional dependency diagram. which i have posted the question there to indicate its relevance. I wasnt yelling but to bring the attention to the question as its lenghty.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with your `c_cpp_properties.json`:

1. There is no `compilerPath` attribute.
2. You have `intelliSenseMode` as `msvc-x64` but are clearly using `gcc` include paths.

Probably you want to fix (1) by providing the full path to `g++.exe` and (2) by changing `intelliSenseMode` to `gcc-x86`.  Something like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            ...
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86",
            ...
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I also suggest going through the [Getting Started with C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) guide if you haven't already.  Even if you don't ultimately want to set things up the way the tutorial does, it is valuable to have a working configuration to compare to when things go wrong.

Also, in the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), try running "C/C++: Log Diagnostics".  Compare what you see in that output to the output of:

```sh
  $ touch empty.c
  $ g++ -v -E -dD empty.c
```

Ideally, you want those to match as closely as possible.